# How do I create a country state dropdownbar

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am creating a project where I need to create a signup menu with a contigent country state dropdown Bar. I just don't know how to.

Ive tried looking up other stuff but cant find how to do it. Im working in A MVC and just know the basics.

I want to make it so a country dropdown is required first and updates the the state dropdown without reloading the page

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The majority of the code came from 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/cascading-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc
but there were many changes to convert to what you were looking for

Use this for your country and state dropdown in view

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CountryStr, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CountryStr, ViewBag.Country as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StateStr, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StateStr, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "--Select State--", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this below it

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#CountryStr").change(function () {
                $("#StateStr").empty();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("getState")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { id: $("#CountryStr").val() },
                    success: function (State) {

                        $.each(State, function (i, State) {
                            $("#StateStr").append('<option value="'
                                                       + State.Value + '">'
                                                 + State.Text + '</option>');
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        alert('Failed.' + ex);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            })
        });
    </script>
```

add this at the top to load a Country List (using @{   }):

```
string[] whwhw = ListofCountries
IEnumerable<string>
why = whwhw;
SelectList CountryLit = new SelectList(why);
```

and put this in your controller

```
public void bindCountry()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select Country--", Value = "0" });

        cs.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = (da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Country", cs)).ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString(), Value = dr.GetValue(0).ToString()});
            ViewBag.Country = li;
        }
        cs.Close();
    }  
    public JsonResult getState(int id)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> liStates = new List<SelectListItem>();

        liStates.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "--Select State--", Value = "0" });
        cs.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = (da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM State WHERE CountryId = " + id, cs)).ExecuteReader();

        int count = 0;
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            liStates.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = dr.GetValue(1).ToString(), Value = dr.GetValue(0).ToString() });
            ViewBag.State = liStates;
            count += 1;
        }
        cs.Close();
        PersonValues.Country = count;
        return Json(new SelectList(liStates, "Value", "Text", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
    }
```

and put

```
bindCountry();
```

before you return view for the page the dropdown bars are going to be in

Comment: "Edited from" is not a proper way to do attribution when you whole answer copy-pasted from somewhere else... Did you confirm that it is ok to re-license content? Make sure to carefully read https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing

Comment: I believe I fixed my mistake. I have edited the code to fit their specific intention and referenced it at the beginning.